# How to transform Scheme program into Haskell?

Tags: haskell, scheme

I'm going to transform a scheme program into Haskell but I'm having a hard time learning all about Haskell. If you are familiar with SICP, I`m tasked to answer Exercises 3.63, 3.64, 3.65, 3.66 and 3.71. I have already found the answers to these problems but they are written in scheme. Here is the question and answer in 3.63:

> Exercise 3.63. Louis Reasoner asks why the sqrt-stream procedure was not written in the following more straightforward way, without the local variable guesses:
>
> ```
> (define (sqrt-stream x)
>   (cons-stream 1.0
>   (stream-map (lambda (guess)
>   (sqrt-improve guess x))
>     (sqrt-stream x))))
> ```
>
> Alyssa P. Hacker replies that this version of the procedure is considerably less efficient because it performs redundant computation.
>
> Explain Alyssa's answer.
>
> Would the two versions still differ in efficiency if our implementation of delay used only `(lambda () <exp>)` without using the optimization provided by memo-proc (section 3.5.1)?

Answer:

> In Louis Reasoner’s procedure, `(sqrt-stream x)` is recursively called inside `(sqrt-stream x)`. However, the two streams are not the same variable. Therefore redundant computation is performed. In the original version, a local variable guesses is used.
>
> ```
> (define (sqrt-stream x)
>    (define guesses
>      (cons-stream 1.0
>        (stream-map (lambda (guess)
>             (sqrt-improve guess x))
>                   guesses)))
>    guesses)
> (display-stream (sqrt-stream 2))
> ```

Here is the Haskell code that I wrote and it's not working:

```
module Main
where
guess = 1:: Double
x=0
do
 if ((guess*guess) = x)
  then y = (x + guess) / x
  guess = y
 else
  sqrt x = guess
```

Please help me fix my codes. I need them next week.

I'll also try the other ones and post them here if there there will be errors again. Hope you can help me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should be on stackoverflow, but what errors are you getting? Will it compile?

Comment: Your Haskell code doesn't look like the Scheme answer at all. What is `sqrt-improve`?

Comment: I would suggest that you go through some introductory Haskell tutorials to get a better understanding of the language syntax.  Try http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters or maybe http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/

Answer (score 2):

Your Haskell code looks wrong on so many levels (e.g. do is no loop construct, you can't assign a new value to guess). I can only guess what you want. Here is a function calculating the square root:

```
sqrt' :: Double ->  Double
sqrt' n = loop n
    where loop guess | abs (guess - improve guess) < 0.00000000001 = improve guess
                     | otherwise = loop $ improve guess
          improve guess = 0.5 * (guess + n / guess)
```

Here is a version which gives you the list of approximations (until it doesn't change anymore):

```
sqrt' :: Double -> [Double]
sqrt' n = takeChanging $ iterate (\ guess -> 0.5 * (guess + n / guess)) n  
          where takeChanging (x:y:ys) | abs (x-y) < 0.00000000001 = [x] 
                                      | otherwise = x : takeChanging (y:ys)
```